# Qt one signal to multi slot. And there are 2 connection type slots. Will there be any problems?

Tags: qt, connection, signals, slot

Different classes and threads try to send one signal to two or more slots.
There are two types of slots: queue and direct.
Is it okay to use both DirectConnection and QueuedConnection for slots?
ex)

```
B.cpp
A* a = A::sharedInstance();
connect(a, &A::signal, this,&B::slots, Qt::DirectConnection);

C.cpp
A* a = A::sharedInstance();
connect(a, &A::signal, this,&C::slots, Qt::DirectConnection);

D.cpp
A* a = A::sharedInstance();
connect(a, &A::signal, this,&D::slots);
```

The signal was transmitted only through QueuedConnection slots.

Comment: It's rare to need explicit `Qt::DirectConnection`. If intention is to  call slot of an object possibly living in a different thread, then you have to be very careful to make the slot thread safe. Easier and safer if you just don't do it.